# Laravel routing returns error: "Class LoginController does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm attempting to create a "create user"-form using Laravel and Blade.

My form is as follows:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'create_user']) }}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Form::email('email') }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Form::password('password') }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

The 'create_user' name refers to the following route:

```
Route::post('user/new', array('as' => 'create_user', 'uses' => 'LoginController@store'));
```

I have a .php-file called 'LoginController.php' with the function:

```
public function store()
{


    if (Auth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password'))) {
        return Auth::user();
    }

    return "Failed.";
}
```

My routing table looks like this:

[image: Routing table]

But when I submit a form with valid data, I get the error message:

[image: Error]

I've tried running "php artisan dump-autoload", but it didn't change anything.

EDIT: Adding full LoginController.php on request. (Pardon the lacking indentation.)

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

class LoginController extends \BaseController
{

public function create()
{

}

public function store()
{


    if (Auth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password'))) {
        return Auth::user();
    }

    return "Failed.";
}
}
```

Comment: Can we see the full `LoginController.php` please?

Comment: @lukasgeiter - Ah, of course. Added. I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something essential and obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have put the controller into a namespace (`app\controllers`)

You either have to remove that or adjust your route:

```
Route::post('user/new', array(
    'as' => 'create_user',
    'uses' => 'app\controllers\LoginController@store'
));
```

Comment: Perfect. Should I avoid using namespaces for Laravel-specific stuff all together? There seems to be a lot of magic going on behind the scenes, which is quite sensitive.

Comment: No I wouldn't say this. In fact, in the next version, Laravel 5, the whole application is namespaced. What you can do is wrap a [route group](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups) around all your routes and then set the namespace of that group to `app\controllers`

Answer (score 0):

In the routes i've always used resource instead. It handles the methods for you.

```
Route::resource('yourRoute', 'YourController');
```